# How can i solve and plot this non linear ODEs usin NDSOLVE?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, differentials, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to solve the following non-linear ODEs

```
Eqn1 = n*(-f''[x])^(n - 1)f'''[x] - mf'[x]^2 + (m*(2*n-1)+1)/(n+1)f[x]f''[x]+ M2^2f'[x] == 0; , 
Eqn2 = n(-theta'[x])^(n - 1)theta''[x] + (m(2 *n - 1) + 1)/(n + 1)f[x]theta'[x] - mf'[x]theta[x] == 0;
```

where `m,n, alpha, b and M2` are parametes, with 5 boundary conditions

```
f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1 + alpha f''[0], f'[N1] == 0, theta[0] == 1 + b theta'[0], theta[N1] == 0
```

please help me

Comment: Please enter the code in a more readable format. You can read about the formatting options here: [Markdown help#Code and Preformatted Text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: What does " `` BC3 = f'[N1] == 0 " mean? Further, assignments are written with 1 and equation with 2 equal signs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so there are a lot of quantities in the OP that are not defined and/or discussed but I used some made up values to demonstrate the procedure.

I am changing `theta` to `g` for my own convenience.

Set up the equations

```
Eqn1 = n*(-f''[x])^(n - 1) f'''[x] - 
   m f'[x]^2 + (m*(2*n - 1) + 1)/(n + 1) f[x] f''[x] + M2^2 f'[x] == 
  0; Eqn2 = 
 n (-g'[x])^(n - 1) g''[x] + (m (2*n - 1) + 1)/(n + 1) f[x] g'[x] - 
   m f'[x] g[x] == 0;
```

Setting up the made up values for the parameters

```
m = 1;
n = 2;
alpha = 1;
b = 1;
M2 = 2;
N1 = 0;
```

You solve `Eqn1` with the following piece of code

```
sltn = NDSolve[{Eqn1, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1 + alpha f''[0], 
    f'[N1] == 0}, f[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False, 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxSteps -> Infinity] // Flatten
```

And you can actually plot the solution to look at it

```
Plot[f[x] /. sltn, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Of course, without further clarification, not much progress can be made but hopefully the above is a basic guiding principle.

Edit: Let me demonstrate the solution for both functions. I am doing this for clarity.

With the above initializations you run the following

```
sltn = NDSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1 + alpha f''[0], 
    f'[N1] == 0, g[N1] == 0, g[0] == 1 + b g'[0]}, {f[x], g[x]}, {x, 
    0, 10}, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False, 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxSteps -> Infinity] // Flatten
```

And then you can plot your solutions

```
Plot[f[x] /. sltn[[1]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}]
Plot[g[x] /. sltn[[2]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-10, 1}}]
```

If you want to solve for more general values of the parameters you might want to look up the `ParametricNDSolve` command [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Probably N1>0 is upper limit of x.
sltn = NDSolve[......, {x, 0, N1}....

Comment: I do not disagree with you, however, there are not enough clarifications in the OP and my intention was to provide some code with the basic guiding principles so the user can apply it to the actual problem